# jQuery typeahead stops working when I select an option from the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I'm using jQuery typeahead to do an autocomplete that works perfect at first, but when I select an option from the list and then I try to use it again (by typing in the input) it simply doesn't show results again.

Looks like typeahead get destroyed when I select an option.

**Update #1**

I've created a jsfiddle to you to be able to see what's happening, you can type "someone" in the input to get autocompleted data: http://jsfiddle.net/cristiangrojas/rhtd9o8k/3/

```
var Opportunities = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(
      '{id} {name} {identification} {email} {vehicle_registration}'.assign({
        "id": d["id"],
        "name": d["name"],
        "identification": d["identification"],
        "email": d["email"],
        "vehicle_registration": d["vehicle_registration"]
      })
    );
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: opportunities
});

Opportunities.initialize();

$('input[name="opportunities_search"]').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLenght: 1
}, {
  name: 'oportunidades',
  displayKey: 'id',
  source: Opportunities.ttAdapter(),
  templates: {
    empty: [
      '<div class="empty-message">',
      'No se encontró ninguna oportunidad',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
        '<p>' +
        'Opp #{{ id }}' +
        '<br>' +
        '{{ name }}' +
        '<br>' +
        'CC: {{ identification }}' +
        '<br>' +
        'email: {{ email }}' +
        '<br>' +
        'Placa: {{ vehicle_registration }}' +
        '</p>'
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with the issue?

Comment: I've just updated the question with the sample code and the jsfiddle url which is the following: http://jsfiddle.net/cristiangrojas/rhtd9o8k/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md

> displayKey – For a given suggestion object, determines the string representation of it. This will be used when setting the value of the input control after a suggestion is selected. Can be either a key string or a function that transforms a suggestion object into a string. Defaults to value

You are using a key string of 'id', but your json data for id is not a string its a number. So either change your json data to have the id as a string or use a function to return the id as a string as in this fiddle:

```
displayKey: function(d){return d.id+'';},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rhtd9o8k/19/

Where `d` is the suggestion object returned and appending an empty string to the id attribute is an easy way to cast a number to a string in javascript.

Comment: Forgot to mention, typeahead was not being destroyed it just hit an error when it tried to compare the previous value of the input to the current value of the input which happens after you select an item.